# How can I scroll and reach to end of Combo box fast in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I scroll and reach to end of Combo box fast like the second time? At the first time after opening form scrolling 7000 records takes 13 secs to reach end of file.Records don't move during moving scroll bar handle and move when handle stops.After reaching end of file, now records move during moving handle and I can go from start to end without delay. It seems that something loads into memory.

Comment: *it seems that something loads into memory* - yup. 7000 combobox items. ...and if you have 7000 items in your combobox, you seriously need to consider other options. A search box, perhaps.

Comment: You can't "scroll fast" until the data is cached.  You need to either unbind the control and cache your lookup, or rethink the design so you don't need to cache 7000 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ComboBox` isn't *meant* to hold that many items. Cut it down to 10-20 items maximum, and make the contents of the dropdown depend on what the user types in the `TextBox` part of the "combo" - select only the top X few records that match the "search" value.

[Search as you type with MS Access Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33892474/1188513) seems like a good place to start (minus the line numbers and redundant comments I guess).

Comment: With typing I can select without problem, But because the users are using Excel list box now and they select through this list box very fast without typing, I wanted to have the quality of Excel list box.

Comment: Your question was about a combobox in Access...... regardless; a user-friendly UI doesn't give 7000 choices to pick from.