# Using Down/Up Arrow key in combo box to select data without updating the data until hitting tab or enter MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

when using a filter while typing in a combo box, the UP arrow key and down arrow key are not useful because once you click down/up the data in the combo box is updating and the list narrows down to only the selected item.
is there a way to select data from the combo list without updating the box itself so the up/down key can be used?

I'm using the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59990955/13522629 , to filter my combo box it is very helpful to filter but I'm having the problem with using the up/down arrow keys.

can anyone help with that.

Comment: Maybe. Review https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/vba-code-for-arrow-keys/d0eaf970-1595-4655-a9c4-95053ae36051

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to answer. but just for reference.

I have updated the mentioned answer with additional functionality (for reference) to achieve partial search (you can call it google search or fuzzy search.

As I have been searching for the same question with no answer. it looks like the only way to achieve that is to put a text box above the combo box (they become Ultrabox). then you can manipulate the (highlighted) or selected items and only update the text box when the user hits enter or tab.

Comment: It's still relevant and thanks for your answer, though I'm not sure what you mean by ultrabox, if you don't mind explaining.

Comment: Never mind the naming. the idea is to place a text box above a combobox. Use the text box text as a filter (using the mentioned function) for the (partially hidden) combobox. trap the keys, tap, enter to reflect your changes on the combobox and fire the update event.